# What are the core items for a jellymancer?

Tags: brogue

I haven't picked up this game in a while and it looks like there were a lot of nifty updates.  I want to give jelly wrangling a try but I don't have a clue as to what type of items I will need to keep an eye out for.  So what kind of items should I be seeking if I wanted to become a Jellymancer?

Comment: I haven't played the game, but do you mean the trick with wand of domination + wand of healing?

Comment: @Pubby I know you'll need at least a wand of domination and some way of healing split jellies, but i'm wondering if there's anything else that can boost its effectiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have run the Jellymancer build, I always have a wand of domination and a staff of healing (highly enchanted, around 5 or 6 charges).

Other nice items for the Jellymancer build:

Ring of Wisdom - Reduces cooldown on staff of healing.

Scroll of Identify - Identify your staff of healing, so you don't waste turns finding out your staff is out of charges.

Shattering Charm - This is nice for allowing you jellies to surround enemies, as jellies are fairly useless in corridors.

Things to be careful of:

Scrolls of Discord - These will decimate your entire jelly force as they attack each other.

Caustic Gas - This will easily kill the lower health jellies, which are about 80% of your force.

Confusion Gas - Jellies will attack each other, killing a lot. You might get lucky and have some survive, but they will be at a low health.

Fire - Jellies die really quickly, and fire spreads.